# Where can get information on browser version changes?

Tags: internet-explorer, version, cross-browser

When a new browser comes out, where can I got to get a technical understanding of how this will effect my code?

For example, when IE9 came out, my site displayed incorrectly as opposed to IE8.

When IE9 becomes IE10, etc. is there somewhere that explains the differences?

One would think that each software company would have a place to go.  In this particular case Internet Explorer.

Comment: See, this is why standards are supposed to exist. If Microsoft were fully CSS compliant (I think they're close now) this wouldn't be an issue. Microsoft is usually pretty quiet about the new releases though. I personally think it's because it's hard to put a positive spin on "we're still not up to spec, but we're 20% closer!"

Comment: If you want to take a sip of the kool-aid, [Microsoft claims that they're fully CSS compliant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/compare-browsers)

Comment: Newsletters, like [Sitepoint's](http://www.sitepoint.com/newsletter/viewissue.php?id=3&issue=353), do a pretty good job of announcing major changes, new features, and gotchas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there somewhere that explains the differences?

There are various places that will help.

- [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a veteran resource dedicated to mapping the differences between browsers
- [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) also has very well formatted information
- The [Wikipedia Comparison of Web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) will give some broad outlines where differences are to be expected
- MSDN will publish articles on new features of Internet Explorer like

  - [Internet Explorer 9 Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  - [What's new in Internet Explorer 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could watch the different browser's Development blogs and news sites for example or follow the dev news on twitter:

Internet Explorer:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/
- https://twitter.com/IE

Chrome:

- http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/
- http://blog.chromium.org/
- https://twitter.com/ChromiumDev

Firefox:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/devnews/
- https://twitter.com/mozhacks

They give quite a good impression on latest browser changes.